# Looking for a better way to represent unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a bunch of declarations like this:

```
unsigned char configurePresetDelivery[] = { 0x7E, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20, 0x38, 0x0B, 0x04, 0x03, 0xF2, 0x40, 0x59, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE3 };
unsigned char beginPresetDelivery[] = { 0x7E, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20, 0x3C, 0x01, 0x04, 0x2B };
unsigned char configureDirectDelivery[] = { 0x7E, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20, 0x37, 0x02, 0X03, 0XF2, 0xD5 };
...
```

These are commands that I send to a piece of equipment via a serial port.

Would there be a better way to represent these? In a struct or a class or something?

I am limited to C++98.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to better document them.

Comment: One easy improvement would be to make those constants `const`.

Comment: Could be `constexpr`, actually

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Provided they really are constants.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo not in c++98

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will make them constexpr.

Comment: This surely follows some protocol. I would only add a comment pointing to the protocol's documentation.

Comment: Indeed, `constexpr` doesn't work with my compiler, so `const` will have to suffice.  Yes, this does follow a protocol, which will be documtented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you represent the commands is going to depend very much on what command sequences your program is going to send.

If your program is totally general-purpose and needs to be able to send literally any possible sequence of bytes, then a `const unsigned char` array (or `const uint8_t` if you want to be a little bit more explicit) is probably the way to go.

On the other hand, if there are some "rules" to your protocol that you know won't ever change or need to have any exceptions, than you can write your code to include/enforce those rules rather than just blindly sending raw programmer-provided sequences (and hoping the programmer typed them all in correctly).

For example, if you know for a fact that your serial device always requires that every command starts with the prefix `0x7E, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20`, then you can cut down on duplication (and therefore on the chances of making a typo) by removing that prefix from your sequences and having your send-function automatically prepend it, instead, e.g.:

```
const unsigned char configurePresetDelivery[] = { 0x38, 0x0B, 0x04, 0x03, 0xF2, 0x40, 0x59, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE3 };
const unsigned char beginPresetDelivery[]     = { 0x3C, 0x01, 0x04, 0x2B };
const unsigned char configureDirectDelivery[] = { 0x37, 0x02, 0X03, 0XF2, 0xD5 };

const unsigned char prefix[] = {0x7e, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20};

void send_prefix_and_command(const unsigned char * cmdWithoutPrefix, int numBytes)
{
   send(prefix, sizeof(prefix));
   send(cmdWithoutPrefix, numBytes);
}

[...]

send_prefix_and_command(configurePresetDelivery, sizeof(configurePresetDelivery));
```

... and (taking it a bit further) if you know that some of your command-sequences are going to vary based on run-time parameters, then rather than hand-coding each variation, you can create a command-generator function to do it for you (and thus encapsulate the potentially-error-prone generation step into a single code-location, so there's only one routine to maintain/debug instead of many).  E.g.

```
// This is easier to do using std::vector, so I will use it
std::vector<unsigned char> generatePresetDataCommand(unsigned char presetID, unsigned short presetValue)
{
   // I'm totally making this up just to show an example
   std::vector<unsigned char> ret;
   ret.push_back(0x66);
   ret.push_back(0x67);
   ret.push_back(presetID);
   ret.push_back((presetValue>>8)&0xFF);  // store high-bits of 16-bit value into a byte
   ret.push_back((presetValue>>0)&0xFF);  // store low-bits of 16-bit value into a byte
   return ret;
}

// Convenience wrapper-function so later code can send a vector with less typing
void send_prefix_and_command(const std::vector<unsigned char> & vec)
{
   send_prefix_and_command(&vec[0], vec.size());
}

[...]

// The payoff -- easy one-liner sending of a command with little chance of getting it wrong
send_prefix_and_command(generatePresetDataCommand(42, 32599));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy, I very much like the idea of a command-generator function and I will try to implement that in my code.